# What does Art style mean here?

Tags: discussion

I see most of the time comparing the art style. This anime/manga is similar to art style of that anime/manga. And there are some question where name of art style are asked like:

- [Is there a name to the art style used in No Game No Life?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15511/is-there-a-name-to-the-art-style-used-in-no-game-no-life)
- [Is there a name for the art style in Gankutsuou?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9750/is-there-a-name-for-the-art-style-in-gankutsuou)

The knowledge about art style I have is the way of drawing the characteristics of character or different aspect.

Is that all, if not then what is art style. What does it mean here ?

Comment: Sounds to me like you nailed it. That's exactly what art style is.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha at 1st i thought of asking here.Thanx